# WiX: Using SourceDir as the Target of a (Menu) Shortcut

Tags: sandbox, wix4

I'm having a lot of trouble using SourceDir as the target of a shortcut in my WiX script.

I'm now using Wix v4 built under dotnet.

The relevant code is below...

```
    <!-- This property is for the WIX internal usage...
-->
<Property Id="ApplicationFolderName" Value="Mikey\Test" />

<!-- The conversion tool moved the directory structure to the bottom.  I don't know why, I think it properly belongs here still
-->
  <StandardDirectory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
    <Directory Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Name="Where it will all go via the property above I hope" />
  </StandardDirectory>

  <StandardDirectory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
    <Directory Id="MikeyStartMenuFolder" Name="Mikey's Stuff for Testing" />
  </StandardDirectory>


<?define dExcelFolder1="C:\Users\Mikey\OneDrive\Mikey Excel Add-ins" ?>
<?define dExcelFolder2="[SourceDir]..\..\Mikey Excel Add-ins" ?>

<DirectoryRef Id="MikeyStartMenuFolder">
<Component Id="ShortcutsComponent" Guid="8E967B01-F768-4D2C-9D41-0B5ED11F1849">


        <Shortcut Id="MikeyStuffShortcut" Name="Mikeys Stuff Folder" Description="The name is self explanatory" 
                  Target="[APPLICATIONFOLDER]" 
                  WorkingDirectory="APPLICATIONFOLDER" />

        <Shortcut Id="MikeyTestShortcut1" Name="Mikeys Test Folder" Description="Test 1" 
                  Target="C:\Users\Mikey\OneDrive\Development Battambang" 
                  WorkingDirectory="APPLICATIONFOLDER" />

        <Shortcut Id="MikeyTestShortcut2" Name="Mikeys Test Folder 2" Description="Test 2" 
                  Target="$(var.dExcelFolder1)"
                  WorkingDirectory="APPLICATIONFOLDER" />

        <Shortcut Id="MikeyTestShortcut3" Name="Mikeys Test Folder 3" Description="Test 3" 
                  Target="$(sys.SOURCEFILEDIR)"
                  WorkingDirectory="APPLICATIONFOLDER" />

        <Shortcut Id="MikeyTestShortcut4" Name="Mikeys Test Folder 4" Description="Test 4" 
                  Target="[SourceDir]" 
                  WorkingDirectory="APPLICATIONFOLDER" />

        <Shortcut Id="MikeyTestShortcut9" Name="Mikeys Test Folder 9" Description="Test 9" 
                  Target="[APPLICATIONFOLDER]" 
                  WorkingDirectory="APPLICATIONFOLDER" />

        <RemoveFolder Id="CleanUpShortCut" Directory="MikeyStartMenuFolder" On="uninstall" />

        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Mikey\Stuff" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes" />

</Component>

</DirectoryRef>  
<!-- I got this off the internet, but it also doesn't get through the compiler.  Complains about element text
<InstallUISequence>
  <ResolveSource After="CostInitialize"> UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE OR NOT Installed </ResolveSource>
</InstallUISequence>
-->

<InstallExecuteSequence>

 <ResolveSource Before="CostFinalize" Suppress="no" />

</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

The problem is that **MikeyTestShortcut1** through **MikeyTestShortcut4** don't get created.
Note that **MikeyStuffShortcut** and **MikeyTestShortcut9** do work and get created.

What should I do?  I prefer to simply use SourceDir as the Target path.  Ultimately though, I'd like to be be able to hardcode a directory also if I might need that too one day.

I'm posting additional information here since I posted the original question.  I'm using Sandboxie, a new tool for me that I'm still getting used to.

Going via "Programs", it shows Mikey's Stuff Folder and Mikey Test Shortcut 9.

[image: Going via "programs", it shows Mikey's Stuff Folder and Mikey's Test Shortcut 9]

However, going via "(host) Start Menu", it also shows Mikey's Test Shortcut 4, which is in fact the one that referenced SourceDir.

[image: Mikey's Test Shortcut 4 is included here]

So it seems that it may be working.  I don't understand why Sandboxie is showing different icons against the shortcuts, they all seem to be created equally in the code.  But I will keep working on it.
I tried to add Sandboxie to the products list to perhaps attract someone that knows, however I wasn't able to.